# Is there a way to render a row of images in iterm2?

Tags: iterm2

I want to show a row of images in iterm2 using the [inline images protocol](https://iterm2.com/documentation-images.html), but I'm not sure if it's possible.

I'm language agnostic at this point, but nothing I tried in [terminal-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/terminal-image) seemed to work.

I also noticed `Writing images across the page in columns appears to be problematic.` in the provided [imgls](https://iterm2.com/utilities/imgls) source.